# Access the OpenTimestamp api through R

Tags: r, httr

I am working on a simple R package to submit hashes for trusted timestamping and to get timestamp info back through [Origin Timestamps](https://originstamp.org/home). I manage to get the information, but I do not manage to POST it [OpenTimestamp post hash](https://doc.originstamp.org/#!/default/post_hash_string).

I am using the http package in R. My package [ROriginStamp is on github](https://github.com/rkrug/ROriginStamp), and the function which I do not get to work is [store_hash_info()](https://github.com/rkrug/ROriginStamp/blob/master/R/store_hash.R).

Whenever I execute it, I get:

```
> store_hash(hash = "c7be1ed902fb8dd4d48997c6452f5d7e509fbcdbe2808b16bcf4edce4c07d14e")
  Error in store_hash(hash = "c7be1ed902fb8dd4d48997c6452f5d7e509fbcdbe2808b16bcf4edce4c07d14e") : 
  Bad Request (HTTP 400). 
3.
stop(http_condition(x, "error", task = task, call = call)) 
2.
httr::stop_for_status(result$response) at store_hash.R#29
1.
store_hash(hash = "c7be1ed902fb8dd4d48997c6452f5d7e509fbcdbe2808b16bcf4edce4c07d14e") 

>
```

The function is defined as follow:

```
store_hash <- function(
  hash,
  error_on_fail = TRUE,
  information = NULL
) {
  result <- new_OriginStampResponse()
  ##
  url <- paste0("https://api.originstamp.org/api/", hash)
  request_body_json <- jsonlite::toJSON( information, auto_unbox = TRUE )
  result$response <- httr::POST(
    url,
    httr::add_headers(
      Authorization = get_option("api_key"),
      body = request_body_json
    ),
    httr::content_type_json()
  )
  if (error_on_fail) {
    httr::stop_for_status(result$response)
  }
  ##
  try(
    {
      result$content <- httr::content(
        x = result$response,
        as = "text"
      )
      result$content <- jsonlite::fromJSON( result$content )
    },
    silent = TRUE
  )
  ##
  return(result)
}
```

The function `get_option("api_key")` just returns my api key.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

---

**Edits**

Thanks to [Thomas Hepp](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/originstamp/ipjetu_MOAE), Here is a curl command which does work:

```
curl 'https://api.originstamp.org/api/ff55d7bc3fe6cb2958e4bdda3d4a4a8e528fb67d9194991e9539d97a55cda2a3' \
-H 'authorization: YOUR API KEY' \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
-H 'accept: application/json' \
-H 'user-agent: OriginStamp cURL Test' \
--data-binary '{"url":null,"email":null,"comment":"this is a test","submit_ops":["multi_seed"]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not familiar with R.  But, it’s possible to timestamp a file using opentimestamps.org, by posting a hash of the file to one of their calendar servers, using the following methodology.  There is no need for an API key, and this procedure can be used to prove the existence of the file at a point in time, via a reference to a value stored in the OP_RETURN field of a bitcoin transaction, in a block in the bitcoin blockchain.

As an example, first, create a test file:

```
$ echo -n 'this is a test...  this is only a test...' > file.txt
```

Now, take a sha256 hash of the file:

```
$ sha256sum file.txt
```

This produces:

```
c16d7c8e23baf68525cf0a42fff6b394fdba1791db9817fd601b3f73e2f5fbca
```

Now, to create a timestamp of the file, post the raw bytes of the hash to one of the calendar servers (e.g. https://a.pool.opentimestamps.org/).  This can be done using curl, like so:

```
$ echo -n 'c16d7c8e23baf68525cf0a42fff6b394fdba1791db9817fd601b3f73e2f5fbca' | xxd -r -p |  curl -X POST --data-binary - https://a.pool.opentimestamps.org/digest > out.ots
```

[Optional:  If you don’t want to disclose the hash of the file that you are timestamping to Opentimestamps, you can add a random salt to the file hash, then do sha256(original file hash + salt) and post the result of this.]

The response from the above request is redirected to a file out.ots.  To get the status of the timestamp, we need to parse the raw bytes of out.ots.

First, view the raw bytes of the file using a hex editor, or xxd:

```
$ xxd out.ots 
00000000: f010 95ee b35a b002 5b8b 5e76 3522 6970  .....Z..[.^v5"ip
00000010: 886c 08f1 0462 be3e 32f0 081a ff1c ae94  .l...b.>2.......
00000020: 4f00 4600 83df e30d 2ef9 0c8e 2e2d 6874  O.F..........-ht
00000030: 7470 733a 2f2f 616c 6963 652e 6274 632e  tps://alice.btc.
00000040: 6361 6c65 6e64 6172 2e6f 7065 6e74 696d  calendar.opentim
00000050: 6573 7461 6d70 732e 6f72 67              estamps.org
```

Some of the bytes represent instructions, as follows:

```
f0 xx:  append xx bytes
f1 xx:  prepend xx bytes
80: sha256 hash
00: stop
```

Start with the hash that we timestamped:

```
c16d7c8e23baf68525cf0a42fff6b394fdba1791db9817fd601b3f73e2f5fbca
```

then, proceed by parsing the response of the POST request.  The first two bytes are f0 10.  This means append the next 16 bytes (10 in hex is 16 in decimal).  This produces:

```
c16d7c8e23baf68525cf0a42fff6b394fdba1791db9817fd601b3f73e2f5fbca95eeb35ab0025b8b5e7635226970886c
```

Continuing parsing the POST response, the next byte is 80.  This means take the sha256 hash of the above.

```
echo -n ‘c16d7c8e23baf68525cf0a42fff6b394fdba1791db9817fd601b3f73e2f5fbca95eeb35ab0025b8b5e7635226970886c’ | xxd -p -r | sha256sum
```

produces:

```
f7d0917a163a8df26066cd669eb12e2d0d59bb5f454aaee338dcc0694ef35090
```

Continuing, we have f1 04.  This means prepend the next 4 bytes to the above.  This produces:

```
62be3e32f7d0917a163a8df26066cd669eb12e2d0d59bb5f454aaee338dcc0694ef35090
```

Next, we have f0 08.  Append the next 8 bytes.  This produces:

```
62be3e32f7d0917a163a8df26066cd669eb12e2d0d59bb5f454aaee338dcc0694ef350901aff1cae944f0046
```

Finally, we have 00.  This means stop.  At this point, skip the next 10 bytes, then extract starting from this point to get the URL that we’ll need to get the status of the timestamp:

https://alice.btc.calendar.opentimestamps.org

then, concatenate ‘/timestamp/’ followed by the result above:

https://alice.btc.calendar.opentimestamps.org/timestamp/62be3e32f7d0917a163a8df26066cd669eb12e2d0d59bb5f454aaee338dcc0694ef350901aff1cae944f0046

The status of the timestamp can be accessed by making a GET request to the above URL:

```
curl https://alice.btc.calendar.opentimestamps.org/timestamp/62be3e32f7d0917a163a8df26066cd669eb12e2d0d59bb5f454aaee338dcc0694ef350901aff1cae944f0046
```

returns:

```
 Pending confirmation in Bitcoin blockchain
```

If you wait a few hours, the confirmation will be written to the bitcoin blockchain, and the above GET request will return a much longer proof like the one above, eventually chaining-up to a value that is written to the OP_RETURN field of a bitcoin transaction, in a block in the bitcoin blockchain.  By saving this proof, you can verify the existence of the file at the point in time that the block was written to the blockchain, without the need to query the Opentimestamps servers.

The following python script automates the above procedure:

```
import hashlib
import requests

filehash=bytes.fromhex('c16d7c8e23baf68525cf0a42fff6b394fdba1791db9817fd601b3f73e2f5fbca')

server='https://a.pool.opentimestamps.org/digest'
print('posting ' + filehash.hex() + ' to ' + server)
response=requests.post(url=server, data=filehash)
bytearray=response.content

print('saving response to ./out.ots')
f=open('./out.ots', 'wb')
f.write(bytearray)
f.close()


print('analysing response')
i=0
ptr=0x00
result=filehash
while(True):
    print(i)
    print('ptr:', hex(ptr))
    nextinstruction=bytearray[ptr]
    if(nextinstruction==0xf0):
        #append
        ptr+=1
        numberofbytes=bytearray[ptr]
        ptr+=1
        bytesegment=bytearray[ptr:ptr+numberofbytes]
        print('append ', bytesegment.hex())
        result=result+bytesegment
        ptr+=numberofbytes
    elif(nextinstruction==0xf1):
        #prepend
        ptr+=1
        numberofbytes=bytearray[ptr]
        ptr+=1
        bytesegment=bytearray[ptr:ptr+numberofbytes]
        print('prepend ', bytesegment.hex())
        result=bytesegment+result
        ptr+=numberofbytes
    elif(nextinstruction==0x08):
        #sha256
        print('sha256')
        result=hashlib.sha256(result).digest()  
        ptr+=1
    elif(nextinstruction==0xff):
        #fork
        print('fork')
        ptr+=1
    elif(nextinstruction==0x00):
        #stop
        print('stop')
        ptr+=11
        url=bytearray[ptr:].decode()
        url=url + '/timestamp/' + result.hex()
        print('url: ', url)
    else:
        print('invalid ots file format')
        quit()


    print('result:', result.hex())
    print('-----')

    i+=1

    if(nextinstruction==0x00): break

print('to get status of timestamp, make a GET request to ' + url)
print('GET ' + url)
response=requests.get(url)
print(response.text)
```